# Opening an existing word document, editing its bookmarks and saving as new document using Open Xml method

Tags: openxml

I want to open a document file using Open Xml Open Method, search for bookmarks inside the document, assign text from textboxes or labels in aspx page to the bookmarks and finally save it to a new document. Before I was using the Office Interop Word Method. Now I want to try the same thing in Open Xml Method. But I am not able to achieve it. Could you help me? Thanks in Advance.

For your reference my office interop code was as below,

```
object Nothing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;

    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();

    object srcFileName = Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl(@"~/HRLetter\Arabia\Templates\Employment Certificate.doc"));

    Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open
   (ref srcFileName, ref format, ref Nothing, ref Nothing,
   ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing,
   ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing,
   ref Nothing, ref Nothing);

        object bookmarkDate = "Date";
        wordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkDate).Select();

        wordApp.Selection.Text = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", lblRequestdate.Text);

        string DocName;
        DocName = string.Format("{0}_employment_certificate", lblRequestNo.Text);
        hFilename.Value = DocName;
        wordDoc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl(@"~/HRLetter\Arabia\Letters\" + DocName + ".doc")));


        wordDoc.Close(ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing);
        if (wordDoc != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDoc);
            wordDoc = null;
        }

        wordApp.Quit(ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing);
        if (wordApp != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
            wordApp = null;
        }
    GC.Collect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve it using Open Xml method.